# JFileChooser and the "Details View"

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

When using a JFileChooser there is a "Details View" button.
There are 5 pieces of information displayed per file.
Icon, Name, Size, Type, and "Date Modified".
What class controls the 'Type' value?
Using the class 'FileView', the Icon and Name can be controlled.
Using the class 'File', the Size and "Date Modified" can be controlled.
The type descriptions are very good and I would like to use them in other places, also I have some "New" types that I would like to be able to give a 
"Type" description to.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileView>>getTypeDescription()
```

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileView.html#getTypeDescription%28java.io.File%29

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: NO, class 'FileView' methods do not change the "Type" column values in the 'JFileChooser'.

Comment: +1, @Joe, If you override the method, then I'm sure you can return whatever "description" you want. But I would override the method on the JFileChooser, not the FileView.

Comment: No.  I tried that, the 'JFileChooser' 'Type' column is NOT at all, in any way, influenced by the by the type description methods of FileView.

Comment: @camickr thanks @Joe I am pretty sure it is sir, have to post my code in another answer, just a minute.

Comment: Camickr... thanks.  The 'getTypeDescription' method of 'JFileChooser' does give control over what 'type' string is displayed. Now the question is in what class was the type string created?

Comment: You need to parse the File object to determine what description you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.io.*;


public class A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("f.jpg");
    JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
    System.out.println(j.getTypeDescription(f));
}
}
```

The output is on my system:

> F:>javac A.java
>
> F:>java A
>
> IrfanView JPG File

This is because i have IrfanView installed on my system; JFileChooser/FileView>>getTypeDescription() queries the system (in my case Windows) for this information. To "add your own descriptions" you can (like **camickr** said) override getTypeDescription() or you can add it to your system (in the case of Windows in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The problem is that, in your example "f.jpg" is a real file.  The calculation of the "type" name is made form more than the file extension.  For example if you just made up a name like "Bubba.jpg" the type description would be "Generic Type".  I was hoping to see what class actually computed the "type" value.  JFileChooser has no "setTypeDescription method and setting the type in FileView does not change or modify the Type description in the JFileChooser type column.

Comment: No, it does not look into the file; i can make a 0 byte file (e.g. with notepad), name it "f.jpg", run my program and it will say `IrfanView JPG File`. As I have said, it looks up this information in the registry (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) on the basis of the extension (e.g. "jpg").

Comment: Just did a quick test and overriding the getTypeDescrition method of the JFileChooser class does not alter the Type information shown in the "Type" column when in "Details View".

Comment: Then change your registry (see above)

Comment: I extended the File class and create new files with the 'createNewFile' method, but none of the files created are anything but 'generic type'

Comment: 'code'    public FakeFile(String pathname, long length, long lastModifiedTime) {
        super(pathname);
        try {
            createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in FakeFile constructor cannot creatNewFile: " + e);
        }
        deleteOnExit();
        this.length = length;
        setLastModified(lastModifiedTime);
    }

Comment: I would show the code but pasting code seems to be impossible. Putting <code> and </code> tags around the code does not allow proper formatting, nor does putting 'code' at start of code.  What is the way to paste code into a comment?  (the 5 minutes for composing a comment rule is a "winner")

Comment: yea, no-code-in-comments and 5-min-edit-limit are both annoying

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have to do to override the type-information in Java is instantiate JFileChooser with your own subclass of FileSystemView.

- subclass FileSystemView to MyFileSystemView
- override getSystemTypeDescription(File f)
- in that overrride for your special file-type return whatever you want and return the default-value by returning the value from using a super-call otherwise
- instantiate your FileChoosers with one of the following prototypes, giving your custom MyFileSystemView as second argument

> JFileChooser(File currentDirectory, FileSystemView fsv)
>
> JFileChooser(String currentDirectoryPath, FileSystemView fsv)

Comment: Thank you.  From this, I was able to fix the problem.  Calling super on getSystemTypeDescription was not OK.  But creating an empty JFileChooser and returning its value for getTypeDescription solved the problem.